# Unable to inject a query while recreating SQL Injection example

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sql-injection

I'm trying to re-create a SQL injection example but not getting any output after injecting my payload in the query.

Relevant part of the code

```
 

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : 'password',
   database : 'node_db'
 });



app.post('/search_guest', (req, res)  => {
   const room_no = req.body.room_no;
   const sql = 'SELECT * FROM guest WHERE room_no = ' + room_no ;
   connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error executing query:', err);
    return;
  }
  res.send(results);
```

I tried multiple payloads including UNION SELECT, ORDER BY etc but nothing seems to work.

Error I get:

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "SELECT * FROM guest WHERE room_no = 103'UNION SELECT * FROM sensitive_table"
```

I am expecting the code to be vulnerable and respond to a SQL Injection attack by throwing data from other tables which otherwise isn't directly to the client.

Comment: Why did you write a literal `'` before `UNION`?